# Extract full link from a list in Google colab

Tags: pandas, numpy, google-colaboratory, data-extraction, information-extraction

I'm trying to extract a column of links from this kind of rows in a column

```
{'type': 'uri', 'value': 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q47099'}
```

To this:
http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q47099

Basically I would like to extract in a column diferent links like this one with pandas in Google Colab so I was using this code line after importing the csv:
(**org is the column in my csv file and links is the new column created**)

```
data['links']=data['org'].str.findall('http://www.wikidata.org/entity/')
```

Then I tried with this other one:

```
data[data['org'].str.contains('www.wikidata.org')]
```

But both gave me the same result this:

Output from `data.head(5).to_dict()`

```
    {'links': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'org': {0: "{'type': 'uri', 'value': 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q47099'}",
  1: "{'type': 'uri', 'value': 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q565020'}",
  2: "{'type': 'uri', 'value': 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q576490'}",
  3: "{'type': 'uri', 'value': 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q590897'}",
  4: "{'type': 'uri', 'value': 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q604034'}"},
 'orgLabel': {0: "{'xml:lang': 'en', 'type': 'literal', 'value': 'Grupo Televisa, owner of TelevisaUnivision'}",
  1: "{'xml:lang': 'en', 'type': 'literal', 'value': 'Cuponzote'}",
  2: "{'xml:lang': 'en', 'type': 'literal', 'value': 'Casas GEO'}",
  3: "{'xml:lang': 'en', 'type': 'literal', 'value': 'Empresas ICA'}",
  4: "{'xml:lang': 'en', 'type': 'literal', 'value': 'Atletica'}"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `org` column contains a real dict, use:

```
data[data['org'].str['value'].str.contains('www.wikidata.org')]
#               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you want to extract the link:

```
data['links'] = data['org'].str['value']
```

**Update**

Your column looks like a dict but it's a string. You have to evaluate before with `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

data['org'] = data['org'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
data['links'] = data['org'].str['value']
print(data)

# Output
                                    links                                                org                                           orgLabel
0   http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q47099  {'type': 'uri', 'value': 'http://www.wikidata....  {'xml:lang': 'en', 'type': 'literal', 'value':...
1  http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q565020  {'type': 'uri', 'value': 'http://www.wikidata....  {'xml:lang': 'en', 'type': 'literal', 'value':...
2  http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q576490  {'type': 'uri', 'value': 'http://www.wikidata....  {'xml:lang': 'en', 'type': 'literal', 'value':...
3  http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q590897  {'type': 'uri', 'value': 'http://www.wikidata....  {'xml:lang': 'en', 'type': 'literal', 'value':...
4  http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q604034  {'type': 'uri', 'value': 'http://www.wikidata....  {'xml:lang': 'en', 'type': 'literal', 'value':...
```

Comment: I added an update at the end with a screenshot using your formula, I undestand what you said but actually it didn't work. You can see in the screenshot apearing the NaN with your second line.
The First line didn't work because it not contains a dict.
Thanks

Comment: For me it looks like a dict. What is the output of `type(data.loc[0, 'org'])`?

Comment: Using that line give me an error:
`unexpected EOF while parsing`

Comment: Update your post with the output of `df.head(5).to_dict()` (not an image, data)

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: Yeah it actually works thanks. And I can use the same code to get the value from another colums with the same format thanks